# Requesting StreetView images from specific dates

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

With the advent of the new 'historical' street view available in various places - is it possible to make an API request to somehow choose which date I want? I guess I'd have to get a list of 'available images' first - is this planned?

Or at an even more basic level - how can I find out what date the image was taken on that I am getting back from a normal street view image api request.

Thanks so much for your time.

Ramo

Comment: This is available on Google Maps, but is it available in the API yet? I can't find much information about it...

Comment: No, nor can I - I guess part of the question is to the google team about how they will make this available. The second part of the question I think is still valid with the existing service.

Comment: The `StreetViewPanoramaData` object has an `imageDate` property that returns the year and month when the imagery was acquired. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageDate` for StreetView has now been made available as part of [`google.maps.StreetViewPanoramaData`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?authuser=2#StreetViewPanoramaData).